# Symfony2 - git deploy project which directories

Tags: django, deployment, symfony

I used to deploy Django projects into production with git.
There I had simply to track the entire *app*.

Now I'm creating a new project with Symfony2 trying to respect the standard structure.
I would like to know the best practices to deploy it with git.

Basically there are a couple of main folders where I make modifications

```
Symfony/app/
Symfony/src/Me/
Symfony/web/
```

Should I track only those directories or the entire `Symfony` structure ?
Should I find a way to put my whole project into a Bundle ?

Maybe dumb question, I'm new to Symfony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple [recipe in Symfony 2 Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html) for using Git.

Comment: Ho good ! I didn't see this how to in the official docs. Thank you for pointing me the good track